# Eclipse Symbol Resolution only works when broken out

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, android

I have two pieces of source code, the first compiles fine but the second throws a typical "could not be resolved" error. It's probably important to note that I am developing opencv C++ code in eclipse for my Android project using the OpenCV4Android project which does increase the complexity of the job eclipse has.

Code that compiles no problem:

```
std::vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_desired;
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;
DMatch tmpObj;
KeyPoint tmpKey;
KeyPoint tmpOth;

for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ ){
  tmpObj=matches[i][0];
  tmpKey=keypoints_desired[tmpObj.queryIdx];
  tmpOth=keypoints_desired[tmpObj.trainIdx];
  obj.push_back( tmpKey.pt );
  scene.push_back( tmpOth.pt );
}
```

Code that errors out

> Field 'queryIdx' could not be resolved (along with errors that propogate from this)

```
std::vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_desired;
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;
    for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
{
  obj.push_back( keypoints_desired[ matches[i][0].queryIdx ].pt );
  scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ matches[i][0].trainIdx ].pt );
}
```

As you can see the first piece of code is identical to the second functionally it just takes the objects and stores them temporarily to access the fields. I'm guessing this is some kind of issue with how Eclipse is trying to do it's name resolution recursively. Along with how a lot of the code for these projects is stored in another project inside the eclipse workspace.

Is this worthy of a bug report or am I just being stupid? I don't see any glaring mistakes but maybe I am misusing something basic any help on this I would appreciate.